# Using pandas if_exists = “append” with new columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using the pandas .to_sql() method along with the if_exists=“append” keyword, to update a PostgreSQL database daily.

Now, if I add an entry who has a column that is not already in the table, then I get a UndefinedColumn error.

Is there a way I can still add this entry, with the new column in the PostgreSQL table? With all of the entries for this column null for previous entries?

If not, is there a way I can still append it simply without this column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas.to\_sql with new columns to existing table, add automatically new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354172/pandas-to-sql-with-new-columns-to-existing-table-add-automatically-new-columns)

Comment: do you have any problem with 'replace'? and please share your code